# javascript - find nested property from javascript object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I might have two type of payloads.

```
const payload = {
   "firstName":"Steven",
   "lastName":"Smith"
}
```

or

```
const payload = {
   "personalDetails": {
       "firstName":"Steven",
       "lastName":"Smith"
    }
}
```

How can I retrieve firstName from the payload during a REST API call.

```
const { firstName } = payload;
```

The above code will work for the first payload but it won't for the second payload since `firstName` is nested inside `personalDetails`. Is there a clean of retrieving it in `ES6`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cound take `personalDetails` property if not `undefined` or `null` or just the variable directly.

```
const { firstName } = payload.personalDetails ?? payload;
```

Comment: think `??` is more modern, does not support my codebase.

Comment: you could take logical OR `||` instead.

Answer (score 4):

```
const { personalDetails: { firstName } } = payload;
```

[More](https://medium.com/@pyrolistical/destructuring-nested-objects-9dabdd01a3b8) about destructuring nested objects.

Comment: Its debatable which one is cleaner, for me personally `const { firstName } = payload.personalDetails` seems more cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Strange scenario you have here but this might solve the issue:

`const { firstName } = payload.personalDetails ? payload.personalDetails : payload;`